# SharePoint returns extra system columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I do query to SherePoint. I have created query, viewquery and query options.
Web services returns me great results, but it include some other system columns such as:
`ows_Modified` , `ows_DocIcon`, `ows_Editor`. I don't want them. How do I return only those which is in ViewQuery string?

My queryoptions is:

```
@"<QueryOptions>
                    <IncludeMandatoryColumns>False</IncludeMandatoryColumns><ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' />
                </QueryOptions>";
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Return Only Certain Columns of a List When using the SharePoint Web Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889900/how-to-return-only-certain-columns-of-a-list-when-using-the-sharepoint-web-servi)

Comment: I believe this may be a bug. Neither IncludeMandatoryColumns, nor ViewFieldsOnly seems to get rid of ALL the system fields. And specifying the ViewFields does bring them in first, but it still brings in some system fields besides that.

Comment: I've noticed it brings in the fields you specify in ViewFields first. So you could potentially do a workaround that only returns the first X columns, where X is the number of ViewFields specified.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return only selected columns (and not all of them) use `ViewFields` property of `SPQuery` object. You can find some more information about it and a sample code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields.aspx.

In order to do it from javascript, you can try code as written here (that post is on another topic, but it still shows how to specify fields to select): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33683/spservices-today-not-returning-correct-results.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am not in control, and unable to user SPQuery, I have access only through Web services. Is it possible to achieve the same using CAML?

Comment: Try something like this within the CAML with your query: **[...]<Query>[...]</Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='MyColumnToShow'/></ViewFields>[...]**. Just replace **[...]** with the appropriate caml (that you probably have already written) and put appropriate fields references inside between *ViewFields* opening and closing tag.